# Why is it impossible to define the DTD validation as a process independent from parsing?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

This question is about a comment in the [documentation of Java's `SchemaFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html) but seems not to be Java specific. The `SchemaFactory` class is used to validate XML against an external schema.

The implementation however only supports **RELAX NG** and **XML Schema**, but not **XML DTD**.

It says:

> Note that because the XML DTD is strongly tied to the parsing process and has a significant effect on the parsing process, it is impossible to define the DTD validation as a process independent from parsing. For this reason, this specification does not define the semantics for the XML DTD. This doesn't prohibit implementors from implementing it in a way they see fit, but users are warned that any DTD validation implemented on this interface necessarily deviate from the XML DTD semantics as defined in the XML 1.0.

*From [Oracle Java 10 Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html)*

I'm wondering what are the potential pitfalls that hinder implementors to support validation against external **XML DTD**s?

Answer (score 1):

Validation against external DTDs isn't the problem; the problem is separating validation from parsing. The most obvious reason for this is the way the DTD controls entity expansion, but also there are lots of subtle interactions in the detailed semantics of a DTD - the details of which I'm afraid I have long forgotten.